# Issue with visibility: hidden; and transition in HTML

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="s.css"/>
<div id="xd"><ul>a</ul></div>
```

CSS:

```
#xd ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

Under Chrome 27, the "a" appears for 1 second and then dissapears. How can this happen with visibility: hidden; ?

Please expain why this happens.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using display: none instead of visibility: hidden?

Comment: It works fine! Can you please explain why this happens?

Comment: I'ld anwser but @Netizen did it for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `visability:hidden` and `display:none` in CSS.  For what you want, I would do something like this instead to mitigate your issue:

CSS:

```
  #xd ul {
        display: none;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    }
```

HTML:

```
  <ul id="xd"><ul><li>a</li></ul></ul>
```

For an explanation of the difference between the two, here is a link with more info: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Essentially, to paraphrase the above link, `visability:hidden` preserves the space around the element and will still affect the rest of the layout, whereas `display:none` does not affect the rest of the layout and works as if the element is completely removed from the page.  So, there may be a quirk in Chrome which displays the `visability:hidden` element first before it is hidden because of that.

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/JKA8z/